# ClassCast Exception when trying to Instatiate For same appModule Class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, weblogic12c

i'm trying to instantiate AppModule Programmatically

but i  get classCastException

that a DefaultContext is proper for this use. Memory leaks and/or unexpected behaviour may occur if the automatic initialization is
 performed improperly. This message may be avoided by performing
 initADFContext before using getCurrent().>

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.oracle.ocs.adaa.model.AppModuleImpl cannot be cast to com.oracle.ocs.adaa.model.AppModuleImpl
>   at com.oracle.ocs.adaa.services.TreeTraverse.postTree(TreeTraverse.java:53)
>               at com.oracle.ocs.adaa.restwebservice.Client.postStrategyTree(Client.java:35)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>               at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:198)
>               at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>               at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$3.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:174)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>               at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
>               at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:112)
>               at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilterInternal(JpsAbsFilter.java:292)
>               at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:149)
>               at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>               at oracle.security.wls.filter.SSOSessionSynchronizationFilter.doFilter(SSOSessionSynchronizationFilter.java:294)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>               at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3706)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3672)
>               at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)
>               at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
>               at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>               at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)
>               at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
>               at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
>               at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
>               at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
>               at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>               at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
>               at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
>               at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

and this is the code

```
private static AppModuleImpl am = null;
private static final String AM_CONFIG_NAME = "AppModuleLocal";
private static final String AM_DEF_NAME =     "com.oracle.ocs.adaa.model.AppModule";

public static void postTree(JSONObject json) throws Exception{

    am = (AppModuleImpl) Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(AM_DEF_NAME, AM_CONFIG_NAME);
    }
```

UPDATE #1 :
When google this exception , its said because of the same class has been loaded many times by different class loaders at run time

and my  application structure is like the following :
1 Model Project 
and 
Project 1  which have model.jpr output as a dependency //
project 2 also have model.jpr output as a dependency

and the Ear for the application contain a war file for project 1 and a war  project 2 
inside each war there is a .jar file for the model

im not sure if that is the reason (by having model jar many times )
but is there is   a way to make a shared jar for both projects ??

Answer (score 0):

First, we don't need the whole stack trace, first 10 lines or so is enough. Second always indicate version of product. Third, is this in ADF BC custom code or ADF Faces Backing Bean? I assume backing bean/code for the UI? Then the next question is WHY are you instantiating the AM in the client??? This is very bad practice and you are specifically told NOT to do this as all interaction with the ADF BC should be through the binding container and exposed methods for the AM or VO.

Comment: thanks for your reply
this is application that don't contain any UI
It just contain Model Project and RestService Project 
so  i need to use appModule Programitcly